# How do I pass a command to the component of another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have two activities. When an item in a RecyclerView is selected, it takes the user to the second activity and fills in the details with the related RecyclerView item.

In the second RecyclerView activity, there is a Spinner. Depending on the item selected in the spinner, different RecyclerViews become visible/invisible to the user on the second activity.

How do I make it work so that the information is sent from the first activity to command the spinner on what to do?[This is how Second Activity looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roQjD.png)

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView tv_title, tv_description;
    private ImageView PartiesThumbnailImg,PartiesCoverImg;
    private RecyclerView RvPartyMembers;
    private PartyMembersAdapter partyMembersAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parties_detail);

        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spnConstituencies);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.constituencies, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //ini views
        iniViews();

        //Setting up members list
        setupRvPartyMembers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


    void iniViews() {
        RvPartyMembers = findViewById(R.id.rv_party_members);
        String partiesTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        String partiesDescription = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
        int imageResourceId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("imgURL");
        int imagecover = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("imgCover");
        PartiesThumbnailImg = findViewById(R.id.detail_members_img);
        Glide.with(this).load(imageResourceId).into(PartiesThumbnailImg);
        PartiesThumbnailImg.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
        PartiesCoverImg = findViewById(R.id.detail_members_cover);
        Glide.with(this).load(imagecover).into(PartiesCoverImg);
        tv_title = findViewById(R.id.tvPartyTitle);
        tv_title.setText(partiesTitle);
        tv_description = findViewById(R.id.tvPartyDesc);
        tv_description.setText(partiesDescription);
    }

    void setupRvPartyMembers(){
        List<PartyMembers> mdata = new ArrayList<>();
        mdata.add(new PartyMembers("name",R.drawable.members_brendangriffin_fg));
        mdata.add(new PartyMembers("name",R.drawable.members_brendangriffin_fg));
        mdata.add(new PartyMembers("name",R.drawable.members_brendangriffin_fg));

        partyMembersAdapter = new PartyMembersAdapter(this,mdata);
        RvPartyMembers.setAdapter(partyMembersAdapter);
        RvPartyMembers.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    }
```

These are the important pieces of code of the FirstActivity.java

```
 @Override
    public void onPartiesItemClick(PartiesOireachtas partiesOireachtas, ImageView partiesImageView) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),PartiesDetailActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("title", partiesOireachtas.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("description",partiesOireachtas.getDescription());
        intent.putExtra("imgURL", partiesOireachtas.getThumbnail());
        intent.putExtra("imgCover",partiesOireachtas.getCoverPhoto());
```

and

```
Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        //RecyclerView Setup
        //int data

        lstPartiesOireachtas = new ArrayList<>();
        lstPartiesOireachtas.add(new PartiesOireachtas("Fianna Fáil", "example1", R.drawable.fianna_fail_logo,R.drawable.fianna_fail_cover));
        lstPartiesOireachtas.add(new PartiesOireachtas("Sinn Féin", "example2", R.drawable.sinn_fein_logo,R.drawable.sinn_fein_cover));
        lstPartiesOireachtas.add(new PartiesOireachtas("Fine Gael", "example4", R.drawable.fine_gael_logo,R.drawable.fine_gael_cover));
        lstPartiesOireachtas.add(new PartiesOireachtas("Green Party", "example9", R.drawable.green_party_logo,R.drawable.green_party_cover));
        lstPartiesOireachtas.add(new PartiesOireachtas("Social Democrats", "example3", R.drawable.soc_dems_logo,R.drawable.soc_dems_cover));
        lstPartiesOireachtas.add(new PartiesOireachtas("Independent", "example2", R.drawable.independent_party_logo,R.drawable.independent_party_cover));
```

Comment: You might want to check Android architecture articles. They answer your question as well as solve many other questions you will have later on.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably noticed an activity doesn't have a default constructor, but uses an onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method. This means you should pass your information using this Bundles, or use something like SharedPreferences / SQLite. Since SharedPreferences / SQLite is a bit overkill for this in my opinion, you can add the object upon creating an intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("name", parcelableObject);
```

If you want to pass a custom object you have to implement the Parcelable interface, this is pretty straightforward since you can basically auto generate all code for this in Android studio (just hit alt-enter a few times). For more information you can check out the following link.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable

In the receiving activity you can do the following:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Object object = bundle.getObject("name"); //Don't forget to cast!
```